# Can I downgrade gcc in centos 64 bit?

Tags: linux, gcc, cuda

i am using centos 6.4 which has gcc with version 4.4.7 but CUDA 5 require gcc version 4.4.5 as per following link [CUDA-toolkit-release-notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux)

How can I downgrade gcc to 4.4.5 or below without causing harm to my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think 4.4.7 will be OK. If you're having trouble using 4.4.7, please post a new question with the details of the problems you are having. Although the link you reference mentions 4.4.5, that simply means what CUDA was tested with. If you look in `/usr/local/cuda/include/host_defines.h` you will see that the enforced limit is 4.6.x or below:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)

#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 6)

#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.7 and up are not supported!

#endif /* __GNUC__> 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 6) */

#endif /* __GNUC__ */
```

If you really want to install a different gcc/g++, it is possible, you can search on those topics on stack overflow, or on the web.  [Here's one example](http://linuxwell.com/2011/10/30/multiple-versions-of-gcc-on-fedora-15/) on the web of a how-to site that explains installing an arbitrary version of gcc/g++ alongside the version that ships with your OS.  It mentions Fedora 15 but the instructions should work OK for your CentOS 6.4

Comment: but i am not getting actual output besides my program is working fine on another machine with tesla c1060 CUDA 4.2 with gcc version 4.1.2

Comment: Are you doing cuda error checking on all cuda calls and kernel calls